# Remove white spaces from fields - Logstash

Tags: logstash, key-value, elastic-stack, removing-whitespace

Message:
key1=val1,  key2=val2,  key3=val3

Below is my logstash filter:

```
    filter {
grok {
            "match" => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:msg_timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:kvFields}"
            }
        }
    kv {
                 source => "kvFields"
                 field_split => ","
                 trim_key => " "
                 trim_value => " "
           }
    }
```

Logstash Output:

```
{
 "key1" => "val1",
 "  key2" => "val2",
 "  key3" => "val3"
}
```

Here i want to remove spaces in all fields. I tried with trim_key => "\s" in kv filter. still no luck.

Please help to remove spaces in all logstash fields if there is any other approach.

Comment: I did some search and I keep seeing trimkey instead of trim_key. Maybe try that with " " and "\s"?

Comment: No such keyword existsis the output. I am using 5.5 version.